In cpp, extract code block to meth cause sigsegv
Following is err code, it raise err in ort_session.Run
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "onnx_helper.h"
#include "ndarray.h"
#include "opencv_helper.h"
#include "vector_helper.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <onnxruntime_cxx_api.h>

class OnnxHelper2Test : public testing::Test {
protected:
//    static void SetUpTestCase() {
//    }
};

std::pair<std::vector<float>, Shape> handle_input_img(const std::string &input_img_path) {
    // Load the image using OpenCV
    cv::Mat input_mat = cv::imread(input_img_path);

    // Convert to float
    cv::cvtColor(input_mat, input_mat, cv::COLOR_BGR2RGB);
    input_mat.convertTo(input_mat, CV_32F);
    // Normalize

    input_mat /= 255.0;
    // Convert the preprocessed image to a vector of floats
    Ndarray<float> input_img = mat_to_ndarray(input_mat);

//    std::string r = xarr_to_str(xa);
    input_img.transpose({2, 0, 1});
//    const std::string &xa_str1 = xarr_to_str(xa);
//    std::cout << xa_str1 << std::endl;
    input_img.expand_dims(0);
//    const std::string &xa_str2 = xarr_to_str(xa);
//    std::cout << xa_str2 << std::endl;

    return {input_img.data, input_img.shape};
}

void handle_out_img(Ort::Value &output_tensor, const std::string &out_img_path) {
    // Post-process the output
    auto out_img = tensor_to_ndarray(output_tensor).get_sub(0);
    auto out_shape = out_img.shape;
//    float *data_ptr = const_cast<float *>(tensor_data);
//    cv::Mat out_img(out_shape[2], out_shape[3], CV_32FC3, data_ptr);

    // Transpose the image
    out_img.transpose({1, 2, 0});

    // Scale the image to the range [0, 255]
    out_img *= 255;
    out_img.clip(0, 255);
    std::vector<uint8_t> out_img_int_data(out_img.data.begin(), out_img.data.end());

    // Save the output image using OpenCV
    auto out_mat = cv::Mat(out_img.shape[0], out_img.shape[1], CV_8UC3,
                           out_img_int_data.data()); // CV_8UC3 means 8u uint8_t + channel 3

    cv::cvtColor(out_mat, out_mat, cv::COLOR_RGB2BGR);
    cv::imwrite(out_img_path, out_mat);
}

// Method to set up the ONNX Runtime session
Ort::Session newSess(const std::string &onnx_model_path) {
    Ort::Env env(ORT_LOGGING_LEVEL_WARNING, "onnxruntime");
    Ort::SessionOptions se_opts;
    OrtCUDAProviderOptions cudaProviderOpts;
    cudaProviderOpts.gpu_mem_limit = 2 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
    se_opts.AppendExecutionProvider_CUDA(cudaProviderOpts);
    se_opts.SetGraphOptimizationLevel(GraphOptimizationLevel::ORT_ENABLE_EXTENDED);
    se_opts.SetExecutionMode(ExecutionMode::ORT_SEQUENTIAL);
    Ort::Session ort_session(env, onnx_model_path.c_str(), se_opts);
    return ort_session;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    // Load the ONNX model
    auto d = "/home/roroco/Dropbox/cpp/cpp_lib/test/fix/onnx";
    std::string onnx_model_path = std::format("{}/RealESRGAN_x4plus_anime_6B.onnx", d);

//    // Set up the ONNX Runtime session
//    Ort::Env env(ORT_LOGGING_LEVEL_WARNING, "onnxruntime");
//    Ort::SessionOptions se_opts;
//    OrtCUDAProviderOptions cudaProviderOpts;
//    cudaProviderOpts.gpu_mem_limit = 2 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
//    se_opts.AppendExecutionProvider_CUDA(cudaProviderOpts);
//    se_opts.SetGraphOptimizationLevel(GraphOptimizationLevel::ORT_ENABLE_EXTENDED);
//    se_opts.SetExecutionMode(ExecutionMode::ORT_SEQUENTIAL);
//    Ort::Session ort_session(env, onnx_model_path.c_str(), se_opts);
    auto ort_session = newSess(onnx_model_path);

    Ort::AllocatorWithDefaultOptions allocator;
    std::string input_name = ort_session.GetInputNameAllocated(0, allocator).get();
    std::string out_name = ort_session.GetOutputNameAllocated(0, allocator).get();

    // Perform inference
    std::vector<const char *> input_names = {input_name.c_str()};
    std::vector<const char *> out_names = {out_name.c_str()};

    Ort::MemoryInfo memoryInfo = Ort::MemoryInfo::CreateCpu(OrtAllocatorType::OrtArenaAllocator,
                                                            OrtMemType::OrtMemTypeDefault);

    // Load and preprocess input image
    std::string input_img_path = std::format("{}/small.jpg", d);

    auto [input_tensor_vector, input_shape] = handle_input_img(input_img_path);
    // Create the input tensor
    Ort::Value input_tensor = Ort::Value::CreateTensor<float>(
            memoryInfo,
            input_tensor_vector.data(),
            input_tensor_vector.size(),
            input_shape.data(),
            input_shape.size());

    // Create a vector of input tensors
    std::vector<Ort::Value> input_tensors = {};
    input_tensors.push_back(std::move(input_tensor));
    std::vector<Ort::Value> out_tensors = ort_session.Run(Ort::RunOptions{nullptr}, input_names.data(),
                                                          input_tensors.data(), input_tensors.size(),
                                                          out_names.data(), out_names.size());

    // Handle the output image
    const std::string &out_path = std::format("{}/out.jpg", d);
    handle_out_img(out_tensors[0], out_path);
    std::cout << std::format("out to {}", out_path);
}

When I don't use newSess and put all newSess code in main it work, following is correct code
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "onnx_helper.h"
#include "ndarray.h"
#include "opencv_helper.h"
#include "vector_helper.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <onnxruntime_cxx_api.h>

class OnnxHelper2Test : public testing::Test {
protected:
//    static void SetUpTestCase() {
//    }
};

std::pair<std::vector<float>, Shape> handle_input_img(const std::string &input_img_path) {
    // Load the image using OpenCV
    cv::Mat input_mat = cv::imread(input_img_path);

    // Convert to float
    cv::cvtColor(input_mat, input_mat, cv::COLOR_BGR2RGB);
    input_mat.convertTo(input_mat, CV_32F);
    // Normalize

    input_mat /= 255.0;
    // Convert the preprocessed image to a vector of floats
    Ndarray<float> input_img = mat_to_ndarray(input_mat);

//    std::string r = xarr_to_str(xa);
    input_img.transpose({2, 0, 1});
//    const std::string &xa_str1 = xarr_to_str(xa);
//    std::cout << xa_str1 << std::endl;
    input_img.expand_dims(0);
//    const std::string &xa_str2 = xarr_to_str(xa);
//    std::cout << xa_str2 << std::endl;

    return {input_img.data, input_img.shape};
}

void handle_out_img(Ort::Value &output_tensor, const std::string &out_img_path) {
    // Post-process the output
    auto out_img = tensor_to_ndarray(output_tensor).get_sub(0);
    auto out_shape = out_img.shape;
//    float *data_ptr = const_cast<float *>(tensor_data);
//    cv::Mat out_img(out_shape[2], out_shape[3], CV_32FC3, data_ptr);

    // Transpose the image
    out_img.transpose({1, 2, 0});

    // Scale the image to the range [0, 255]
    out_img *= 255;
    out_img.clip(0, 255);
    std::vector<uint8_t> out_img_int_data(out_img.data.begin(), out_img.data.end());

    // Save the output image using OpenCV
    auto out_mat = cv::Mat(out_img.shape[0], out_img.shape[1], CV_8UC3,
                           out_img_int_data.data()); // CV_8UC3 means 8u uint8_t + channel 3

    cv::cvtColor(out_mat, out_mat, cv::COLOR_RGB2BGR);
    cv::imwrite(out_img_path, out_mat);
}

// Method to set up the ONNX Runtime session
Ort::Session newSess(const std::string &onnx_model_path) {
    Ort::Env env(ORT_LOGGING_LEVEL_WARNING, "onnxruntime");
    Ort::SessionOptions se_opts;
    OrtCUDAProviderOptions cudaProviderOpts;
    cudaProviderOpts.gpu_mem_limit = 2 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
    se_opts.AppendExecutionProvider_CUDA(cudaProviderOpts);
    se_opts.SetGraphOptimizationLevel(GraphOptimizationLevel::ORT_ENABLE_EXTENDED);
    se_opts.SetExecutionMode(ExecutionMode::ORT_SEQUENTIAL);
    Ort::Session ort_session(env, onnx_model_path.c_str(), se_opts);
    return ort_session;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    // Load the ONNX model
    auto d = "/home/roroco/Dropbox/cpp/cpp_lib/test/fix/onnx";
    std::string onnx_model_path = std::format("{}/RealESRGAN_x4plus_anime_6B.onnx", d);

    // Set up the ONNX Runtime session
    Ort::Env env(ORT_LOGGING_LEVEL_WARNING, "onnxruntime");
    Ort::SessionOptions se_opts;
    OrtCUDAProviderOptions cudaProviderOpts;
    cudaProviderOpts.gpu_mem_limit = 2 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
    se_opts.AppendExecutionProvider_CUDA(cudaProviderOpts);
    se_opts.SetGraphOptimizationLevel(GraphOptimizationLevel::ORT_ENABLE_EXTENDED);
    se_opts.SetExecutionMode(ExecutionMode::ORT_SEQUENTIAL);
    Ort::Session ort_session(env, onnx_model_path.c_str(), se_opts);
//    auto ort_session = newSess(onnx_model_path);

    Ort::AllocatorWithDefaultOptions allocator;
    std::string input_name = ort_session.GetInputNameAllocated(0, allocator).get();
    std::string out_name = ort_session.GetOutputNameAllocated(0, allocator).get();

    // Perform inference
    std::vector<const char *> input_names = {input_name.c_str()};
    std::vector<const char *> out_names = {out_name.c_str()};

    Ort::MemoryInfo memoryInfo = Ort::MemoryInfo::CreateCpu(OrtAllocatorType::OrtArenaAllocator,
                                                            OrtMemType::OrtMemTypeDefault);

    // Load and preprocess input image
    std::string input_img_path = std::format("{}/small.jpg", d);

    auto [input_tensor_vector, input_shape] = handle_input_img(input_img_path);
    // Create the input tensor
    Ort::Value input_tensor = Ort::Value::CreateTensor<float>(
            memoryInfo,
            input_tensor_vector.data(),
            input_tensor_vector.size(),
            input_shape.data(),
            input_shape.size());

    // Create a vector of input tensors
    std::vector<Ort::Value> input_tensors = {};
    input_tensors.push_back(std::move(input_tensor));
    std::vector<Ort::Value> out_tensors = ort_session.Run(Ort::RunOptions{nullptr}, input_names.data(),
                                                          input_tensors.data(), input_tensors.size(),
                                                          out_names.data(), out_names.size());

    // Handle the output image
    const std::string &out_path = std::format("{}/out.jpg", d);
    handle_out_img(out_tensors[0], out_path);
    std::cout << std::format("out to {}", out_path);
}

I think both code are same, why does first code raise err

I strongly recommend staying away from meth. It will ruin your life.

You would be better  off by providing backtrace , e.g. like https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime/issues/2397 did. And that library got somany undocumented edge cases (andpossible bugs) that sometimes only dev can tell what's wrong.

It doesn't explicitly state that it does in the documentation but I'd imagine that Ort::Session keeps a reference to env which is then a dangling reference once newSess returns. You'll need to create env outside newSess:
Ort::Session newSess(Ort::Env& env, const std::string &onnx_model_path) {
    Ort::SessionOptions se_opts;
    OrtCUDAProviderOptions cudaProviderOpts;
    cudaProviderOpts.gpu_mem_limit = 2 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
    se_opts.AppendExecutionProvider_CUDA(cudaProviderOpts);
    se_opts.SetGraphOptimizationLevel(GraphOptimizationLevel::ORT_ENABLE_EXTENDED);
    se_opts.SetExecutionMode(ExecutionMode::ORT_SEQUENTIAL);
    Ort::Session ort_session(env, onnx_model_path.c_str(), se_opts);
    return ort_session;
}
Ort::Env env(ORT_LOGGING_LEVEL_WARNING, "onnxruntime");
auto ort_session = newSess(env, onnx_model_path);

